# ActionScript 3.0, Flash freezes in gotoAndStop()

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I am making a flash file, I am using Adobe Flash CS6 to make it and so using ActionScript 3.0 for coding, I have a kind of "a link" called "About", it should move the flash to a frame that has the "About" content which number is 290 here in my case.

Here is my code for clicking on the "About" button:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var frameNumber:int;
var counter:int;

function onClick3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (counter%2 == 0)
    {
        frameNumber = currentFrame;
        gotoAndStop(290);
    }
    else
    {
        gotoAndStop(frameNumber);
    }
    counter++;
}
aboutButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick3);
```

This should display the "About" frame on even clicks (starting from zero) and go back to the frame that "About" was clicked from on odd clicks, like this:

Click on "About" --> Show About.

Another Click on "About" --> Hide About and go back to the calling frame.

Another click on "About" --> Show About.

And so on..

It works well for moving between a frame and the "About" frame (290), but the problem is that I have a "Next" and "Previous" buttons too, but when I come back from the "About" page, the whole flash freezes and nothing work except the "About" button, so what is the problem here ? What can solve this ?

And if there exist, is there a way to display my "About" section as a pop-up message in flash ?

Comment: What exactly is your logic behind the whole counter thing?

Comment: @David

"This should display the "About" frame on even clicks (starting from zero) and go back to the frame that "About" was clicked from on odd clicks".


I tried it again but with an "About" button and a "Back" button so I got rid of the counter, but still getting the same freeze.

Comment: Are you sure the "counter" has initial value? make sure it has a 0 as a default value for example. The freeze can happen due to runtime error, null error as an example.